# SQL Server Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server

I have stopped seeing the tables of my project inside the SQL Server Object Explorer.

I have to mention that I had to reinstall my Visual Studio 2017 but did not make any changes to my project.

This is how my SQL Server Object Explorer looks atm

[image]

Recently I made a migration and a database update without problems but well, I can't explore my tables. Any idea on how to restore the view?

Thanks in advance!

SQL Server Management Studio

[image]

Comment: You mean your whole database vanished? Because what you have expanded are system databases.

Comment: Indeed. I only see the system databases but no the project database. I expanded everything but found nothing

Comment: What do you see in SSMS?

Comment: @JacobH Updated post with picture of SSMS!

Comment: Based on what I see, the server name is different in SSMS and VS. You are probably not connecting to the right server instance. Also, their versions are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you may be looking at two different SQL Servers.  In the first image it looks like you're looking at `LocalDb`.  In the second, it looks like you're looking at a full-blown SQL Server instance.

See if you can't connect to your `LocalDb` and try again.